# android buttons id is swapping after save

Tags: android-layout

```
i have make application consist of 40 button
```

,but the problem is that every time i make the button ids and save the code i found that the button ids is swaped with the other btn ids thanks for your help
first layout
`

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_red"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_btn" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_blue"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:max="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_color"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/aqua"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:text="@string/prev_lay"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_green"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_red"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_red"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_effect"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bt_color"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bt_color"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/aqua"
        android:text="@string/more_effects"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bt_effect"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_blue"
        android:background="@color/White" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bt_color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/power"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bt_effect"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_blue"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_green"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_green"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_green"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_b3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_red"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/orangeStrong" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_w3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_green"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:background="@color/g2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_blue"
        android:background="@color/b2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:lay*emphasized text*out_alignBottom="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/r3"
        android:background="@color/p" />`
second
```

`  **strong text**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Color" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_w3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:background="@color/w3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_g3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/r3"
        android:background="@color/g3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_b3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:background="@color/b3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:background="@color/r3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:background="@color/r4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:background="@color/b4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/g4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:background="@color/g4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/w4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:background="@color/w4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/r5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_r4"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_g3"
        android:background="@color/r5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/g5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/r5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/r5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_b3"
        android:background="@color/g5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/g5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/g5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_w3"
        android:background="@color/b5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/w5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/w4"
        android:background="@color/w5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bck"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/w5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:background="@color/aqua"
        android:text="@string/bck"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

thanks for your attentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i samply find the answer you need only to use drop down list of eclipse click on button u need to change its id then change id then preview make sure that u do not make click expent on